# Sketchup - slicing

Tags: sketchup

I have been trying to slice objects with a plane but it doesn't work.

I watched youtube videos, etc but in my case, no matter what I just can't make it work.

[Here is what I am doing (video gif on imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzdm0.jpg)

When I insert a plane inside an object and do the intersection, it creates properly the intersection lines, but these lines are not usable when it comes to consider a surface 'cut'